# Is using the particle の at the end of a sentence considered feminine?

Tags: sentence-final-particles

I need some additional information on gender differences when speaking Japanese.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends.

の in a question to make sure is used by both male and female people. So the following lines can be naturally said by a male or female speaker.

> 「行くの？ 行かないの？」
>
> 「ディズニーランドに行きたいの？」
>
> 「高校で水泳部だったの？」

Assertive sentences which end with の are usually feminine, although there are a few men who use this kind of の. For example,

> 「ディズニーランドに行きたいの。」
>
> 「ミニーちゃんが大好きなの〜〜〜！」
>
> 「『ハムレット』は読んだけど、『リア王』はまだ読んでないの。」

If native Japanese speakers read or hear these sentences above, most of them would think that a girl or woman is saying the sentences.

の following です or ます in an assertive sentence sounds elegant and very feminine. For example,

> 「松田さんは、着物の先生ですの。」
>
> 「日曜は、京都へ行きますの。」

However, if the sentence is strongly assertive, の is naturally used by both male and female people like so.

> 「ディズニーランドに行きたいの！」
>
> 「分かってるの！　分かってるけど、間違えちゃったの！」
>
> 「浮気なんかしてないってば。ずっと、仕事してたの！」

This kind of の can be used in an imperative sentence. For example,

> 「違う、北じゃなくて、南に行くの！」
>
> 「ここでは、大きな声出さないの。」

This kind of imperative sentence is also not gender specific.

If の(no) is pronounced longer like のー(nō), it sounds like a male senior’s talking or dialect. This kind of のー is generally written as のう, although う(u) sound is actually not pronounced.

> 「懐かしいのう。」
>
> 「山口さんは元気かのう。」
>
> 「あの魚は[美味]{う・ま}かったのう。」

の meaning もの or のもの is used by both male and female people. For example,

> 花子「大きいのと小さいの、どっちにする？」
> 太郎「小さいの。」
>
> 太郎「うどんは、関東のと関西の、どっちが好き？」
> 花子「関西の。」

Comment: I wonder, whether in a sentence 「また 戦かのう。」 I’ve seen in a comics, the のう is the one you’re talking about in your answer. It is a senior citizen’s reaction to a situation, when a person that might be spy has been brought to a village. But I am not sure of the gender of the speaker from the drawing.

Comment: @Glutexo If the person is a village resident or from a village, it’s probably dialect のう which means that the person can be male or female. In fictional stories, sometimes, のう is used as an imaginary dialect to express that the speaker is from the countryside, a senior citizen or both.

Answer (score 1):

According to "A Dictionary of Basic Japanese Grammar", page 322 and 324:

の: a sentence-final particle used by a female speaker or a child to indicate an explanation or emotive emphasis.

The の is used by females or children only in an informal situation. There are times when adult male speakers use の in questions, but they do not use it in declarative sentences.

Comment: What term would a male use instead of の？

Comment: There are several that can be used for men. I think it is not a good idea to address a question directly to me. Post a new question so everybody can participate.